# How do I compress a .img file?

Tags: filesystems, openwrt

I have build an image using `openwrt` for `imx6dl` based custom board.

I made the image using `uboot.img` `zImage` `dtb` and `root-imx6` files using this method:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of="$IMAGE_DIRPATH/boot_part.img" bs=1M count=4
parted "$IMAGE_DIRPATH/boot_part.img" mklabel msdos
mkfs.vfat "$IMGAE_DIRPATH"/boot_part.img
mcopy -i "$IMAGE_DIRPATH/boot_part.img" "$IMAGE_DIRPATH/openwrt-zImage " ::zImage
mcopy -i "$IMAGE_DIRPATH/boot_part.img" "$IMAGE_DIRPATH/imx6.dtb" ::imx6.dtb

make_ext4fs -l 125217728 -b 4096 -i 6000 -m 0 "$IMAGE_DIRPATH/root_overlay.img" "$ROOT_DIR" 

dd if=/dev/zero of=Final.img bs=1M count=142
parted Final.img mklabel msdos
dd if=uboot.img of=Final.img bs=1K seek=1 conv=notrunc
parted Final.img mkpart p fat32 1 6
parted Final.img mkpart p ext4 8 140

dd if="$IMAGE_DIRPATH"/boot_part.img of=Final.img bs=1M seek=1 conv=notrunc
dd if="$IMAGE_DIRPATH"/root_overlay.img of=Final.img bs=1M seek=8 conv=notrunc
```

With this I'm able to generate an image of 142MB which is huge. I want generate a compressed image file less than 40MB. Any ideas?

Also suggest if by using other file systems I can get a better compression and can load on SD/eMMC cards.

Comment: You got any luck compressing .img files?

Comment: No. Ext4 doesn't allow compression it seems

Comment: I used `gzip` but compression is a bit cpu intensive